# Playing with Java Final variables - explanation needed - code provided

Tags: java

If you run the below code snippet, you will get this output for the final variable X and Y.

> X = 1 Y = 2 
>   X = 4 Y = 5

Its obvious from the output, the final variables have been reassigned.
I am wondering, if it has violated the contract of Java Final variables. Any thoughts?

```
public class FinalVariablesTest {

private final int x;
private final int y;

public FinalVariablesTest() {
    this.x = 1;
    this.y = 2;
}

public FinalVariablesTest(int xValue, int yValue) {
    this.x = xValue;
    this.y = yValue;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public static void main(String...strings) {
    FinalVariablesTest finalVariablesTest = new FinalVariablesTest();
    System.out.println(" X = "+finalVariablesTest.getX() + " Y = "+finalVariablesTest.getY());

    finalVariablesTest = new FinalVariablesTest(4,5);
    System.out.println(" X = "+finalVariablesTest.getX() + " Y = "+finalVariablesTest.getY());
}
}
```

Comment: In Java, you set the `final` instance variables in the constructor of the class and **cannot** modify this values after this. So, you're not reassigning anything.

Comment: @Greg, you clearly do not understand OOP.

Comment: You're not reassigning. You are creating two instances of FinalVariablesTest. X and Y are instance variables.

Comment: You should read up on the differences between a class variable and an instance variable.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is *not* a violation - There are two separate instances, and each has different `final` values bound to `x` and `y`.

You have changed the instance referenced by `finalVariablesTest`.

Answer (score 0):

`FinalVariablesTest`  class is not singleton, so you can create as many object as you want and different  `FinalVariablesTest  Object` would have different set of x and y final veriable, which you cannot change the value once created, so *this is not a violation*.

Answer (score 0):

These are not exactly variables but rather (final) instance filed. Final instance field can be assigned exactly once, per the object they belong to. Your example creates two objects (you have two `new FinalVariablesTest` expressions) and for each such object the instance fields are assigned with different values.

To see what finality means, try to adding this method to your class:

```
public vod setX(int newValue) {
  x = newValue;
}
```

This change will yield a compilation error due to `setX` trying to assign to a final field after it has already been assigned (in the constructor).

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your variables as Final.

```
private final int x;
private final int y;
```

and you are assigning values to them in the constructor which is perfectly valid. Also you are creating two different instances of FinalVariablesTest having different values which again perfectly legal and correct.

However if you would have done something like

```
private static final int x;
private static final int y;
```

you cannot even initialize it in the constructor.Final fields don't get default values, they have to be explicitly initialized. A final variable can only be initialized once, either via an initializer or an assignment statement. If a final instance variable is not assigned a value - there will be a compiler error !

you have to initialize it while declaring

```
private static final int x = 0;
private static final int y = 0;
```

So lets say you say `private static final int y;` and then without creating any instance of the object you do `System.out.println(FinalVariablesTest.x);` that would be wrong.

Hence what you have done is perfectly valid and legal however with slight variation(making it static so variables now belong to Class rather than individual instances) you cannot do what you have experimented.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(" X = "+finalVariablesTest.getX() + " Y = "+finalVariablesTest.getY()); prints X=1 Y=2 & X=4 Y=5 too because u creating an new object and assigning to already created object.